# Multiple domain names

Tags: javascript

I have a web site that can be reached via either "www.website.co.uk" or via a new second name of www.website.uk. Is there a way that I can find out which of the two names was orginally entered by the user? I have tried  window.location.hostname but that always points to  website.co.uk

Comment: *"I have tried window.location.hostname but that always points to website.co.uk"* It certainly shouldn't, the location object is an accurate representation of the address navigated to. If you're seeing that behavior, it suggests that your `.uk` domain *redirects* to your `.co.uk` domain, so that by the time the JavaScript code runs, you're on the `.co.uk` page.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a permanent redirection for website.uk to website.co.uk
Hence when users entered website.uk it gets redirected to website.co.uk. so, you have to stop the redirection (which might not be a good idea though). Then you will get expected value.

Comment: Yes I believe that is what the hosting company has setup when they added the second domain name. Thank you